# how to add icon or button in jqxgrid next to filter icon when we hover over header row in angular project

Tags: typescript, angular5, jqxgrid, jqxwidgets

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/heegY.png)[please try here.](https://stackblitz.com/github/jqwidgets/angular_demos/tree/master/grid/customfiltermenu/?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

---

I am trying to add button or icon prepend to filter icon or panel open icon in header row when we hover over it.

Feature that already is there : its for filtering the column data

What I want: when we click on our custom icon/button its should clear filter on that column

but **priority** is to add icon/button first

I have added a picture and highlighted the area where i am trying to add close icon

Comment: please add the relevant lines of code to your question, so that we can see whats wrong :) thank you

Comment: @StephanT. i have provided the link to the code above

Comment: Indeed, and you have approximately 400 lines of code in that stackblitz in total, so please specify where you tried to implement your functionality and what exactly went wrong :)

Comment: I just want to find a way to add a button or icon (which jqwidgets already provides but inside panel- <cancel button>),so i want that feature to be visible outside in form of close icon ,which function as a this provided button...hope u understand what i m trying to explain here

Comment: @StephanT. ,please can you help here ,i kinda stuck here for 2 days now

Comment: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/6qwfj4kd/3/) @StephanT. this is the feature i want but in angular ,please have a look